# Crystal Report - Changing DB location not working

Tags: crystal-reports, database-connection

I've worked with Crystal Reports for several yrs but now with a particular report created by another developer, I cannot change the DB connection/location.

He used an OLE DB connection and created the report for use in a Windows App using Visual Studio.  The report works "sort of" in Visual Studio but I have a higher version of VS (VS 2010) than the developer but it is causing issues on the formulas he uses.

I am now just trying to open the report outside of VS directly in Crystal and I can't get it to update the db location.

I created an ODBC linc and tried using it to swap out the db location and it says:

"Data Object cannot be opened/accessed" ... followed by  "Unknown Database Connector Error"

I don't know how to troubleshoot this further.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: How did you try to update it? If you try to create a new connection do you get an error before trying to set it as the datasource?

Comment: No, Justin, no error.  I have created an ODBC connection and upon testing the connection, it is successful.  Even in the database location screens, when highlighting the two stored procedures it is using as the datasource the update button highlights and after that I get the error...

Comment: after hitting update I get the 2 error messages listed in the original posting.

Comment: Are you able to connect using the original OLEDB connection? Why are you trying to change the connection type? Can you be more specific as to what works 'sort of' means?

Comment: 'sort of' means it is working but comes back with an error on the formula... errorkind.  Expecting a number.  The error is bogus because it works within Visual Studio and in Crystal but not through the application on my Windows 7 PC.  It does work on another pc that has Windows XP with the new Crystal distributables installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and was able to resolve it by selecting the `SQL Server Native Client 10.0` driver rather than the `11.0` one when setting up the ODBC connection.

[image]

You have to delete the original if you want to have the same name.